# Run linux command inside a created folder

Tags: python

I need to create a file inside a created folder in linux, the idea is to create a folder each time that the script runs, and then place inside an export of other command

```
import datetime
import time
import os

today=time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
hour=time.strftime('%h')
if(hour<12): h = "00"
else: h ="12"
os.system("mkdir /home/xxx/"+str(today)+""+str(h)+"") 

os.system(“touch test.txt /home/xxx/+str(today)+""+str(h)+""”)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the last line os.system, don't know how to define the created folder as a variable, the "touch" it's an example, the idea is to execute a cli53 command,  and do other things

Comment: I strongly advise you to use `os.makedirs` and `os.chdir` for the task. A lot safer than `os.system` calls as above.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> hour=time.strftime('%h')
> if(hour<12): h = "00"
> else: h ="12"
> ```

does not work. `hour` is a string - you compare it to an integer. Beside that: you never do anything with `h` at all.

---

Use python for all of it?

```
import datetime
import time
import os

today=time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
hour=time.strftime('%H')
if(hour == "12"): 
    hour = "00"
path = r"/home/{}/{}{}".format("xxx",today,hour) 

# create path
if not os.path.exists(path ):
    os.makedirs(path)

# create file
with open(path+"/test.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("")
```

Check:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk("./"):
    print(root,dirs,files)
```

Output: (at 3 pm - timezone has 0-24h clock)

```
#root , dirs, files
./ ['xxx'] ['main.py']
./xxx ['2019060315'] []
./xxx/2019060315 [] ['test.txt']
```

Comment: the idea in the second line is to use cli53 to export a backup dns, so the command will be "cli53 export  test.com > /folderdate/test.txt " something like that